# Tratar con un array que es rellenado dentro de un switch

Tags: php

Tengo un problema, estoy tratando de crear una aplicacion web sencilla que funciona con arrays, ya que es la forma en la que se ha pedido que se haga en clase. He creado una variable array, pero no consigo que esta guarde los valores. Tengo 2 ficheros, uno donde estan las funciones y otra donde esta el programa principal, dejo el codigo de la funcion de insertar datos y dejo el programa principal. El problema es que no guarda ningun dato en el array, pero si le meto datos directamente en el array, si me los coge, asi que estoy un poco perdido en todo esto de php.

```
<?php

    include 'funciones.php';

    // Inicializamos la variable opcion
    $opcion = "";
    $lista = array();

    // Si se ha enviado el formulario
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        // Recogemos el valor del boton pulsado
        $opcion = $_POST['enviar'];
    }
    // Comprobamos la opcion
    switch ($opcion) {
        case 'Insertar producto':
            formularioInsercion();
            // Recogemos los datos del formulario
            if (isset($_REQUEST['enviarInsertado'])) {
                global $lista;
                $nombre = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
                $cantidad = $_REQUEST['cantidad'];
                $precio = $_REQUEST['precio'];
                // Creamos el array con los datos del producto
                $lista[] = array(
                    'nombre' => $nombre,
                    'cantidad' => $cantidad,
                    'precio' => $precio,
                );
            }
            break;
        case 'Modificar producto':
            // Mostramos el formulario de modificacion
            formularioModificacion($lista);
            break;
        case 'Eliminar producto':
            // Mostramos el formulario de eliminacion
            formularioEliminacion($lista);
            break;
        case 'Mostrar lista':
            // Mostramos la lista de la compra
            mostrarListaCompra($lista);
            break;
        default:
            // Mostramos el menu principal
            menuPrincipal();
            break;
    }



    ?>
```

```
    // Funcion que muestra el formulario de insercion
    function formularioInsercion()
    {
        echo "<h1>Insertar producto</h1>";
        echo "<form action='Tarea2.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<label for='nombre'>Nombre del producto</label>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre'>";
        echo "<label for='cantidad'>Cantidad</label>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='cantidad' id='cantidad'>";
        echo "<label for='precio'>Precio</label>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='precio' id='precio'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='opcion' value='insertar'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='enviarInsertado' value='Enviar'>";
        if (isset($_REQUEST['enviarInsertado'])) {
            $lista[] = array(
                'nombre' => $_REQUEST['nombre'],
                'cantidad' => $_REQUEST['cantidad'],
                'precio' => $_REQUEST['precio']
            );
        }
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

Comment: ¿No será porque no pasas `$lista` a `formularioInsercion()`? Prueba a definir la función así: `function formularioInsercion($lista)
{` y al llamarla en el `case` ponlo así: `formularioInsercion($lista);`

Comment: Nada, ni aun asi

Comment: Verifica que las condiciones se cumplen y revisa tus variables.

Comment: Tienes un problema de comprensión, está claro. Veo que usas la variable $lista para crear ese array, que a su vez quieres que contenga más arrays, hasta ahí bien, pero creo que no comprendes que PHP no guarda en ninguna parte esa información una vez terminado de ejecutar el script, sino que solamente existe mientras se ejecuta. PHP no es una base de datos ni un sistema de archivos o de memoria, ni retiene internamente nada una vez termina su ejecución, por lo tanto, si necesitas guardar información, debes decírselo explícitamente durante la ejecución y hacerlo en BD, archivos, memoria, etc.

Comment: El formato en que guardar esa información puede ser array, eso no es problema, pero debes ponerlo en alguna parte externa a PHP, y en la siguiente ejecución del script, donde podría cambiar el $_REQUEST, recoger esa información si es necesario y procesarla como pretendes.

Comment: (cuando digo $_REQUEST me refiero a lo que puede contener, como datos enviados por $_POST, o $_GET o $_COOKIE)

Comment: Si te han enseñado a acceder a bases de datos y como manejarlas, o bien a como crear archivos y poner datos en ellos, ahora es el momento de hacerlo para guardar los arrays, los cuales se guardan como texto, ya sea tal cual o bien serializando los datos o convertidos a JSON, o de cualquier forma que se te ocurra que después sepas ir a buscar y procesar de vuelta para su uso.

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
```

debería ser:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviarInsertado'])) {
```

Por otro lado, estás intentando acceder a la variable $lista dentro de la función pero la variable fue definida fuera de la función. Para eso, deberías hacer:

```
// Funcion que muestra el formulario de insercion
function formularioInsercion()
{
    global $lista;
    ... mas código....
}
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: muy util! Pero igualmente tengo el problema de que no puedo añadir mas datos al array, no entiendo como puedo añadirle datos dentro de una funcion y que se guarden en el array declarada fuera de la funcion.

Comment: @MisterioRojo Veo que no me has leido o no has entendido mis comentarios. Tu código agrega datos al array $lista, pero luego no haces nada con ellos, ni los guardas ni los muestras, y creo que luego esperas que mágicamente, en una segunda petición (la primera ya terminó y se borraron los datos) al pasar por otro case aparezcan de nuevo.

Comment: @MisterioRojo, como dijo @masterguru, le podes pasar la variable `$lista` a la función, o como dije yo, declararla como `global` dentro de la función. De cualquiera de estas dos maneras, podrás usar la variable definida fuera de la función. Y solo la tendrás disponible hasta la última etiqueta de cierre de PHP. Ahora, si la necesitas en otros scripts, podrías usar `$GLOBALS` [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.globals.php) o `$_SESSION`